# counting the number of each word in a dictionary

Tags: string, dictionary, python-3.x, count

I am trying to fix this code:

```
def word_counter (input_str):
    input_str1 = input_str.lower()
    word = 0
    input_str2 = dict(enumerate(input_str1.split(), start=1))
    if word in input_str2:
        input_str2[word] += 1
    else:
        input_str2[word] = 1
    return (input_str2)
word_count_dict = word_counter("This is a sentence")
print(sorted(word_count_dict.items()))
```

so that instead of the output just being:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 'this'), (2, 'is'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'sentence')]
```

it will instead return a count of HOW MANY OF EACH word in input_str as so:

```
[('a', 1), ('is', 1), ('sentence', 1), ('this', 1)]
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter('This is a a a sentence'.split())
>>> c
Counter({'a': 3, 'This': 1, 'is': 1, 'sentence': 1})
>>> c['a']
3
>>> c['This']
1
>>> c.items()
[('This', 1), ('a', 3), ('is', 1), ('sentence', 1)]
```